# Trying to remove autotext from EditText - Android

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

Setting EditText, does not seem to work:

```
android:inputType="text|textNoSuggestions"
```

I am using an S4 on 4.1.x
I want to remove autotext for the edittext field.

Comment: Have you tried 'textNoSuggestions' by itself? I highly doubt it's a solution here, but seems redundant to include both types.

Comment: yup I tried it alone to no avail.

Comment: android:inputType="textNoSuggestions|textVisiblePassword" seems to work....